# documents contains one or more extremely long lines of text

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I'm constantly receiving the following error in a very simple WebProject with 1 html file, 1 js and ext lib included.

---

### Microsoft Visual Studio

### Document contains one or more extremely long lines of text. These lines will cause the editor to respond slowly when you open the file. Do you still want to open the file?

### Yes   No

My VS version is 2008. I don't have long lines in my html. I don't have DB connections. Anyone knows the reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say "ext lib" I assume you mean the [ExtJs](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs) javascript framework. The minified version of the ExtJs framework puts the whole framework on a single line. You can test this by double clicking on the ext-all.css or ext-all.js (not ext-all-debug.js) file in Visual Studio to open it in the editor and you should see the message again. The real annoying part is that the message also shows when the ExtJs library is included in the page head as a script tag (or link tag in the case of the css file). My guess is that Visual Studio is silently opening these files in the background.

Comment: If i hit 'no' there is no intellisense and if i hit yes there is intellisense

Comment: @RizwanMumtaz that makes sense. VS needs to open js files in the background to give you intellisense. If you select "No" to the "extremely long lines" message then it won't open the file. Probably it would make better sense to include the non-minified version in your project when developing.